# This is an anagram program where I am checking if two same length strings are anagram to each other

Tags: c++, anagram

The if statement doesn't terminate the while loop for some reason, which results in unwanted outputs (more than one output). I hope someone can help. Thanks.

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnXbp.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us, *in the question itself*. And don't show images of text, copy-paste it *as text*.

Comment: I also recommend that you learn [how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). And perhaps about the `break` statement.

Comment: Look at end of if statement. Else statement do nothing. And it will go back to for loop if bool_ = false. You should add break to exit the the loop

Comment: Finally, please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: This code `bool_ = false;` terminates the **outer** loop, there's nothing in the code you've written to terminate the **inner** loop. The inner loop is where you get the output from.

Comment: Why not use [std::is_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_permutation)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should `return false` inside if. Try this code.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 


bool areAnagram(string str1, string str2) 
{ 

    int n1 = str1.length(); 
    int n2 = str2.length(); 


    if (n1 != n2) 
        return false; 


    sort(str1.begin(), str1.end()); 
    sort(str2.begin(), str2.end()); 


    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) 
        if (str1[i] != str2[i]) 
            return false; 

    return true; 
} 


int main() 
{ 
    string str1 = "test"; 
    string str2 = "ttew"; 
    if (areAnagram(str1, str2)) 
        cout << "The two strings are anagram of each other"; 
    else
        cout << "The two strings are not anagram of each other"; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Please don't just post code without explanation of what makes it different from the code the OP posted. Explanatory answers are always better than code to copy-paste, as code-only answers tend to lead to [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) which is bad.

Answer (score 0):

First, your `if` statement doesn't break the inner loop. That means that you would output the phrase "NOT ANAGRAM" the number of times the sorted arrays differ. Actually, the number of times minus one (probably), because of the second: the inner loop compares one element less than it should. You should iterate upto `i < len`.
Third, doesn't matter if it is an anagram or not, the program will always output "ANAGRAM" at the end because you set `bool_ = false` right after this output.

Answer (score 0):

@tash29 and @D.Khumoyun

std::string has a `==` operator. You can compare a string by simply writing `if (a == b)`. There is no need for byte wise comparison.

If you use the C++ ternary conditional operator, you can do everything important in one line.

I am sorry, the task is too simple, I cannot explain more . . .

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string a = "ajar";
    std::string b = "stag";

    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    std::sort(b.begin(), b.end());

    std::cout << ((a == b) ? "Anagram" : "Not Anagram");

    return 0;
}
```